# Ubuntu Ati Radeon HD 4500 S official drivers

Tags: ati

I've tried for over a year to get my ATI card to work with Ubuntu but haven't managed to get it to work.

I think that I can install Ubuntu Hardy Heron has the official drivers for my ATI Radeon Mobility HD GPU, so I am thinking about downgraiding to that. Do you think this is a good idea, and do you know if there is a list of officially supported drivers?

Answer (score 0):

1. For such an old version, there aren't any updates any more (a release is supported 18 months, a LTS 3 years) So I'd say NO.
2. There aren't any proprietary ATI drivers for Ubuntu. Sad but true.

Answer (score 0):

Why "haven't managed to get it to work?"

Both the open source xorg driver and the AMD fglrx (Catalyst) drivers should be able to handle your card. You don't even need a legacy driver, a current fglrx should work with 4500!